# How do I specify a data type of uint8 in Numpy getfromtxt?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Does not work:

```
LineValue = np.genfromtxt("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ClassValues/position",dtype=uint8,delimiter=",")
```

Does work:

```
LineValue = np.genfromtxt("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ClassValues/position",dtype=int,delimiter=",")
```

I don't understand why a data type of `uint8` does not work.  In my reading, I have been given to understand I can specify a 1 byte unsigned integer this way.  I don't know that it will or won't cause problems later, but I would prefer it to be cast as a whole number less than 255.

Comment: Can you try `dtype=np.uint8`

Comment: What error did you get in the first case?  Probably `NameError`. That means you are referring to that dtype in the wrong way, not that it won't work.  `uint8` is defined in the `np` namespace, not the base python one.  The string `'uint8'` should also work.

Comment: Saying it "Does not work" is not very informative.  Please give more details.  If the code results in an error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  If there is no error but the result is not what you expected, *show* what you got, and explain why it is not what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using LineValue = np.genfromtxt("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ClassValues/position",np.dtype=uint8,delimiter=",") works, now.
```